# Apple Push Notification service must incorporate the new root certificate (AAACertificateServices) - APNS certificate update

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I got this mail from Apple.

"On March 29, 2021, token and certificate-based HTTP/2 connections to the Apple Push Notification service must incorporate the new root certificate (AAACertificateServices 5/12/2020) which replaces the old GeoTrust Global CA root certificate. To ensure a seamless transition and to avoid push notification delivery failures, verify that both the old and new root certificates for the HTTP/2 interface are included in the Trust Store of each of your notification servers before March 29.

Note that Apple Push Notification service SSL provider certificates issued to you by Apple do not need be to updated at this time."

I configured Firebase as provider server and using APNS authentication Key.

Steps followed:
1.I downloaded AAA certificate
2.Opened in Keychain
3.Tried to export it as p12, not able to do it since it doesn't have private key.
4.Therefore can't export this certificate to Firebase server.

I'm not sure what to do from my end. No documentation for this on apple site or any other site.

To be more specific should I do anything from my end or this should be taken care of by provider server like Firebase?

I'm wondering how  come these instructions are not clearly mentioned by Apple?

Comment: why you are not tried the p8 file concepts

Comment: Because firebase accepts p12 format only.

Comment: may be it helps you : https://mobikul.com/manage-firebase-push-notification-using-p8-file-in-ios/

Comment: I'm already using APNS Authentication Key which is I guess p8 key. I'm talking about the new certificate given by Apple in the mail. What am I supposed to do with that certificate is my question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you're using Firebase, there's nothing to be done on your side. Firebase will handle the job for you, since they are the ones who communicate with Apple. The same applies for any Push service. You should only be concerned if you personally send Push requests to Apple servers.

A more complete explanation about this can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/lh3c4k/apple_push_notif_service_server_certificate_update/gmvnne0/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: I sent a mail to apple development support and the response confirmed the same. Basically this has to be done by notification provider like FCM. Thanks.